# TikZ- best practice for line starting on a circle's edge?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I'd like to know how I can achieve the best seamless crossover between a node (in this case, a circle) and a line starting on that node. I would like the line to only touch the circle's edge. So far I have found 2 methods to achieve some mere results:

- `shorten <=`: It works in a somewhat satisfying fashion after some T & E runs.
- `\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}`: puts the enclosed contentin the background. Does not work very well as it puts the corresponding content (in this case, 2 lines) under other, already existing content (in this case, the "grid").

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[
11pt
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
tikz,
relsize,
amsmath
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}


%% from here on forth TikZ-stuff

\usetikzlibrary{
calc,trees,shadows,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,
decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,
matrix,shapes.symbols,patterns,intersections,fit
}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground layer}
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main,foreground layer}

\tikzset{
>=latex
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small]
%
\draw[style=help lines,step=0.5cm] (0,0) grid (8,6);
%
\draw[->,thick] (-0.1,0) -- (8.5,0) node[anchor=west]{x}; %X-Achse
\draw[->,thick] (0,-0.1) -- (0,6.5) node[anchor=south]{y}; %Y-Achse
%
\draw
(0,0) coordinate (orig)
(3,3) coordinate (B)
(4.5,4.5) coordinate (C)
;
%
\foreach \pt/\labpos in {B/below right,C/below right}{
  \filldraw (\pt) circle (3pt) node[\labpos=3pt,fill=white]{\pt};
};
%
\path[name path=Segment] (B) -- (C);
%highlight segment
\draw
($(B) + (-0.75,0.75)$) coordinate (BPoint)
($(B) + (-0.25,0.25)$) coordinate (BPointExtra)
($(C) + (-0.75,0.75)$) coordinate (CPoint)
;
%\begin{pgfonlayer}{background layer}
\draw[black!60,thick,shorten <=3pt] (B) -- (BPoint);
\draw[black!60,thick,shorten <=2pt] (C) -- (CPoint);
%\end{pgfonlayer}
\draw[black!60,thick,<->,shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt] (BPointExtra) -- ($(C)!(BPointExtra)!(CPoint)$) node[black!60,above=3pt,midway,rotate=45,fill=white]{Segment};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\node[circle,draw,outer sep=1pt] (a) {A};\draw (a) -- ++(135:1cm);`

Comment: What happens if you use `\fill` rather than `\filldraw` to make the circles at (A) and (B)?

Comment: @CharlesStaats That makes the `shorten`-option look way much nicer!

Comment: @percusse I'm sorry, I don't follow.

Comment: Try the code on a simple document.

Comment: Ok to be technically that answers the true question behidn the MWE. You can submit that comment as an answer then. Unfortunately I have been trying to incorporate that into my actual code and I don't seem to grasp how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A rather simple and easy solution is moving the `\filldraw` command after the lines are drawn.  Since the coordinates `B` and `C` were all ready defined, changing when the `\filldraw`ing of the node occurs wont affect the dependencies of the commands using `(B) -- something` or `(C) -- something` and vice versa. Additionally, if you look closely at where the line and circle meet the gray line will be curved where the circle overlaps it and cuts if off; however, shortening a line above it will still have a flat end or rounded if you use `line cap = round`.  These ends will still be over top of the circle or if you shortening too much never meet the circle leaving white space.  This to me will look unnatural.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz,relsize,amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetikzlibrary{
  calc,trees,shadows,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,
  decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,
  matrix,shapes.symbols,patterns,intersections,fit}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground layer}
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main,foreground layer}
\tikzset{>=latex}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small]
    %                                                                               
    \draw[style=help lines,step=0.5cm] (0,0) grid (8,6);
    %                                                                               
    \draw[->,thick] (-0.1,0) -- (8.5,0) node[anchor=west]{x}; %X-Achse              
    \draw[->,thick] (0,-0.1) -- (0,6.5) node[anchor=south]{y}; %Y-Achse             
    %                                                                               
    \draw
    (0,0) coordinate (orig)
    (3,3) coordinate (B)
    (4.5,4.5) coordinate (C)
    ;
    %                                                                               
    %                                                                               
    \path[name path=Segment] (B) -- (C);
    % highlight segment                                                             
    \draw
    ($(B) + (-0.75,0.75)$) coordinate (BPoint)
    ($(B) + (-0.25,0.25)$) coordinate (BPointExtra)
    ($(C) + (-0.75,0.75)$) coordinate (CPoint)
    ;

    \draw[black!60,thick] (B) -- (BPoint);
    \draw[black!60,thick] (C) -- (CPoint);

    \draw[black!60,thick,<->,shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt] (BPointExtra) --
    ($(C)!(BPointExtra)!(CPoint)$)
    node[black!60,above=3pt,midway,rotate=45,fill=white]{Segment};

    %moving the filldraw after the lines being drawn works
    \foreach \pt/\labpos in {B/below right,C/below right}{
      \filldraw (\pt) circle (3pt) node[\labpos=3pt,fill=white]{\pt};
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Using a shortening method will yield a look similar to this just depends on how close you get it.  The problem here is you are trying to put a curved surface up against a straight surface:

[image]

Using a shortening method with a `line cap = round`:

[image]

Placing the line underneath the black circle (this just looks right):

[image]

Comment: It works. I appreciate it, thanks. I'd like to say though it's a technically correct solution instead of a really fitting one, the one I was looking for (some sort of missing option or sth. alike). I'd say users often arrange code snippets by their own opinion of clarity, readability and ... habit. Having this part after the lines is all in all "against" my "rules" for code arrangement.

Comment: @henry I tried using `backgrounds` and then scoping `[on background layer]` but that would put your gray lines under the grid and not visible.  `on background layer` achieves the look I accomplished here, but no matter how I order your picture is ways always placed the gray lines under the grid and not visible.  So to get a solution that doesn't have the sloppy look of shortening or rounding and shortening, I had to move the `filldraw`.

Comment: I must apologize, when I posted the MWE + pictur ein the op I imagined it was self-evident that those specific characteristics were the problematic ones. Sorry for troubling you with the effort.